# I am trying to pass input from an input field into my flask app

Tags: python, forms, post, flask, flask-wtforms

i am looping through data in a Jinja template and I have set the id component of each record as the input for an input field. Each input field has a corresponding submit button. I am trying to send the data from the input field to my Flask app by clicking the submit button but nothing works.

I have tried setting the method to GET and then and then using delete = request.args.get('delInput') in my Flask app but that does not work. I have used various forms of delinput.

```
<tbody>
    <ul>
        {%for id in records%}
            <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{loop.index}}</th>
          <td>{{id[0]}}</td>
          <td>{{id[1]}}</td>
          <th> 
            <form method = 'POST'>
            {{setDel.hidden_tag()}} 
            {{setDel.delInput(value = id[2])}}
            {{setDel.delButton(class="btn btn-danger")}} 
            </form>
    </th>
        </tr>
        {%endfor%}
            </tr>
      </tbody> 


elif setDel.validate_on_submit():
            delete = setDel.delInput.data
            with open('/home/matt/Desktop/test.txt','w') as x:
                x.write(str(delete),'testing')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is not correct. First of all for a form to pass data every field needs to have 'name' attribute set.
Secondly, id[0].. is invalid. Either your fields have a key like `{{id['key1']}}` or if not you use `{{id.0}}, {{id.1}}` etc.
The id name in for loop might trick you.

Comment: if i change the form to <form name = "delete" method = "POST"> then how would i go about getting the data? Also, i i think that the id[0] field is valid because the data is put into its proper place in the table and I know that the data that i want the flask app to recieve is put into a hidden input field because when i change the HiddenField to StringField i can see the proper data

Comment: You didn't get me. The inputs should have attribute name='id_name' so the request.form['id_name'] can be valid.